# How to call non static member function from a static member function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to call a non static member function from a non static member function of the same class such as :

```
  class bintree {
private:
  float root;
  bintree *left;
  bintree *right;


public:
  bintree() : left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {
  }

  bintree(const float &t) : root(t), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {
  }

  ~bintree() {
    if (left != nullptr)
      delete left;

    if (right != nullptr)
      delete right;
  }

  static void niveles(bintree *);

  static bintree *dameBST(float** array, int depth, int left = 0, int right = -1);
  void quickSort2D(float** arr, int left, int right, int n);

};
```

My problem is in dameBST function when I call the quickSort2D the program crush with 'Segmentation fault:11' message.

```
bintree *
bintree::dameBST(float **array, int depth, int left, int right)
{
  int n=0;
  depth++;
  bintree *t = new bintree;
  bintree *tl;
  bintree *tr;

  if(depth%2 != 0) { n = 1; }

  quickSort2D(array, left, right -1, n);
  if (right == -1) {right = 10;}
  if (left == right) { return nullptr; }
  if( left == right - 1 ) { return new bintree(array[left][n]); }



  int med = (left + right) / 2;

  t->root = array[med][n];
  tl = dameBST(array, depth, left, med);
  tr = dameBST(array, depth, med + 1, right);
  t->left = tl;
  t->right = tr;




return t;
```

I don't understand why.

Comment: Don't :), if you need to do that, that means that the static function needs to be a member function in the first place.

Comment: Well, I guess the classic answer would be to pass the instance as a parameter and then call the instance method on that from inside the static function.

Answer (score 1):

Non-static member function is a method that has to be called on the instance of the class. In static context there is no instance. There is only class.

If you have object `t` of class `binkree` you can call method `quickSort2D`:

```
t.quickSort2D(...)
```

**UPDATE**
You can call static methods from non-static functions but NOT vice versa

Comment: Actually it's t->quickSort2D() because member reference type 'bintree *' is a pointer but after changing it that doesn't work either, I have the 'segmentation fault:11'

Comment: @SakinaLaanani sure, I should have changed the name for it... Anyway it seems he didn&#39;t intend to call that method on inctance called `t`. That is why there is an error